# writing a new function but gets an error of stating tuple

Tags: function

```
def myadd1(*arg):

     s=0
     for i in range(len(arg)):
         s+=arg(i)
     return s
```

I am getting error stating that when I enter the values in myadd1 function I get tuple can't be callable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def myadd1(arg):
    s=0
    for i in range(len(arg)):
        s+= arg[i]
    return s
    
    
print(myadd1([1, 2, 3]))
```